# design:attribute on Locked Developer Controlled Package upgrade

Tags: salesforcedx, beta-managed-package, design-attributes

We have been using the 2nd Generation Developer Controlled Packages (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_plan_pkg_types_locked_unlocked.htm) in order to iterate on builds for testing our Lightning Components.

Today we ran into an issue when we tried to utilize a `design:attribute` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm) and it worked fine in our scratch orgs.

However, when we went to upgrade the package in our target Sandbox org by doing a `sfdx force:package2:version:create` and `sfdx force:package:install`, the design component never appeared in the Lightning App Builder, despite being present in the Sandbox org's Developer Console.

Is this a known limitation of package upgrades? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm using Package2 with design attribute and it's working. Can you create a new Package2Version to be sure it's not something that was fixed since you tried ? And then post some of your code maybe if it's still not working ?

Comment: Right - so it still isn't working. I posted a slimmed-down version of my code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/maniax89/cbb58990a6ae9041727d7b6e40aa9110) - like stated initially, this works in scratch orgs when i use `sfdx force:source:push` but does not work when installing packages to a Sandbox org using package2

Comment: Does it have to do with the fact that the package is Locked?

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: @FabienTaillon i was able to get this to work when I use the install URL ->  https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t******** - seems there is some disparity between using the UI and the CLI? or maybe it was just a coincidence that the UI package upgrade worked?

Comment: That's very strange. If you spin up 2 new Scratch Orgs, and install your package, one with the CLI and one the url, do you still see the issue ? If yes that's not good.

Comment: @FabienTaillon it always works on scratch orgs regardless if I use the CLI vs the UI. I just did another upgrade on a Sandbox org using the UI today and the design attribute disappeared, so I have no idea what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We figured out the issue. Turns out the `aura:attribute` referencing the `design:attribute` needs to have `access="global"` in order to appear in the Lightning App Builder.